# Finding the implied domain and image of a composite function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a composite function: $f(x)=\log(\sqrt{2}\sin(x)-1)$

I've been asked to find the implied domain of $f$, as well as the implied range of $f$.

All the examples I've read for composite functions so far have been fairly elementary, using only quotient functions and square roots etc. so I just want to confirm where I'm going wrong here.

The process I went through is as follows:

$\log(x), x > 0$, therefore:

$\sqrt{2}\sin(x) - 1 > 0$

$\sin(x) > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

$\frac{\pi}{4} +2\pi k < x < \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi k$

$\therefore \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x \in [\frac{\pi}{4} +2\pi k < x < \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi k] \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Edit: I understand this is the solution for the implied domain, however I am unsure how to obtain the implied range from here.

Comment: At the first line of your argument, I am already confused.  It is not true that $\log(x) \ge 0$.  For example, $\log(1/\mathrm{e}) = -1$.  I suspect that you mean to say that the *domain* of the logarithm consists only of numbers $x$ such that $x \ge 0$, but this isn't quite right, either, as the logarithm is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: You're right Xander that inaccuracy gave me the solution for the implied domain. Could you potentially show how you would find the implied range, hence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your logarithm to be well-defined, you need $(\sqrt{2}sin(x) - 1 )> 0$, which essentially means that you need $sin(x) > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ 
Since your $sin(x)$ function is $2 \pi$-periodic , and if $x \in [0,\pi]$, then the function is symmetric to $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. If $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, then the function is symmetric to $x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Then if you want your $sin(x) > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, you need $x \in (\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi, \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2k\pi)$, with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, since $sin(\pi - \frac{\pi}{4}) = sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$

For finding the range part, you can see that you have $sin(x) \leq 1$. Then $\sqrt{2} sin(x) - 1 \leq \sqrt{2} - 1$. Then the range is $( - \infty, \log(\sqrt{2} - 1)]$

Comment: That makes sense, how would you approach finding the implied range using this information?

Comment: @vAlkanol I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint for determining the range: Since $\log x$ is an increasing function,

$$a \le f(x) \le b \implies \log a \le \log \big( f(x) \big) \le \log b$$

So what you need to do is establish upper and lower bounds for $\sqrt{2}\sin(x)-1$ over the implied domain.